# Group spark Dataset by month from a timestamp in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-dataset

I've loaded all rows from a table into Dataset using spark session in java. I want to get the count of rows in each month.

I tried to create new column of month by using withColumn() so that I can later use group_by month and count(). But I am not able to get month from timestamp. How can I find the count in each month from above dataset?

My sample Dataset will look like this,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the way you have explained your problem:
I tried to create new column of month by using `withColumn()` so that I can later use `groupBy()` month and `count()`. But I am not able to get month from timestamp.

You can you the static `month()`function provided in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` package to find the month, as below:

```py
myDataset.withColumn("month", month(col("date"))).groupBy(col("month")).count().show()
```

where `col("date")` will have the timestamp (in below case : `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"` ).

Input used:

```
1,2019-04-07  07:24:14,0,8

2,2019-05-07  07:24:14,0,10

5,2019-06-07  07:24:14,0,6

3,2019-04-07  07:24:14,0,7
```

This will give you an output as below:

```
+-----+-----+
|month|count|
+-----+-----+
|    6|    1|
|    5|    1|
|    4|    2|
+-----+-----+
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Tuple2<> type

```
Map<Date, Integer> = myDataSetRDD.map(x -> new Tuple2<Date, Integer>(x.getDate(), 1))
            .reduceByKey((x, v) -> x + v)
            .collectAsMap();
```

This way you end up with a map, that has dates as keys and count of those dates as values.
I hope that helps